# Call multiple modules in route Express, Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is the first time I create an API. I've tried to delete the user items once, the user is removed. I was able to delete the user but i didn't succeed to delete the items.

**User.js**

```
express = require('express');
User = require('./user');
Item = require('../item');
router = express.Router();

User.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).send('User not found by id.');
  }
  Item.deleteMany(user._id, function(err, item) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send('Item is not found');
    }
    return res.status(200).send(user, item);
  });
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this? because I have a feeling that I'm doing it the wrong way.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Error: Item.deleteMany is not a function @Rupesh

Comment: I've added the  `{ user: user._id }` . but i get an error with: **Item is not defined** @MikaS Thanks

Comment: i think the problem is here `Item = require('../item')` .please check the path

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not defining the actual routes -- you need

```
router.route('/').post(function(req, res){ ... });
```

You should also include the body parser to get the parameters out of the request

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var parseUrlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
```

The code you have for User methods will look more like the below block. You can change '/' to the URL path you would rather have the api respond to and can change the code from being in .post to .delete depending on what method you want to respond to

```
route.route('/')
  .post(parseUrlencoded, function(req, res) {
    // code to respond to 'post' methods
    if (!req.params.id) {
      return res.send('id not sent')
    }

    User.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send('User not found by id.');
      }
      Item.deleteMany(user._id, function(err, item) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).send('Item is not found');
        }
        return res.status(200).send(user, item);
      });
    });
  })
  .delete(parseUrlencoded, function(req, res) {
    // code to respond to 'delete' method
  })
```

Comment: @K Thanks for the response I will use your advice! I only have a bug to fix before I can go back to this problem.. I've kinda broke it :( @KatherineR